# Regex formula not looking inside HTML tags

Tags: .net, regex

[My regex pattern](https://regex101.com/r/hrxRQU/1) works for all text not contained within HTML tags:

```
((?<!-)\btest(?!-)\b)(?=[^<>]*(?:<\w|$))
```

In the example below I need it to find both instances of 'test' in these two strings:

```
vdsv ds test dsv sdlvk 
<b>dsjn vkjsd test sv</b>
```

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/zSNoVC/1

Comment: Thank you, to get this working in .Net I had to add periods, like this:

<[^><]*>(.*SKIP)(.*F)|\b(?<!-)test\b(?!-)

Comment: I posted the correct .NET regex solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET, you may leverage an infinite width lookbehind:

```
\b(?<!-)test\b(?<!<[^<>]*)(?!-|[^<>]*>)
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%28%3F%3C!-%29test%5Cb%28%3F%3C!%3C%5B%5E%3C%3E%5D*%29%28%3F!-%7C%5B%5E%3C%3E%5D*%3E%29&i=vdsv%20ds%20test%20dsv%20sdlvk%20%0D%0A%3Cb%3Edsjn%20vkjsd%20test%20sv%3C%2Fb%3E%0D%0A%3Cspan%20test%3D%22Some%20test%20here%22%3Edsjn%20vkjsd%20test%20sv%3C%2Fspan%3E%0D%0A)

In code:

```
var pattern = @"\b(?<!-)test\b(?<!<[^<>]*)(?!-|[^<>]*>)";
```

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?<!-)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `-` immediately to the left of the current location
- `test` - word `test`
- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?<!<[^<>]*)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `<` and any 0 or more chars other than `<` and `>` immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?!-|[^<>]*>)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a `-` or any 0+ chars other than `<` and `>` followed with a `>` immediately to the right of the current location.